# How to diagnose an "invalid data" error message using the r.sun GRASS tool?

Tags: qgis-plugins, grass-gis, lidar

I'm using the r.sun GRASS tool to map solar inputs and shade or lack of it in Pacific NW salmon streams. I clipped out the input raster data (a canopy height model, aspect, slope) for a 15 hectares test area. Everything worked fine, after I got everything into EPSG 102748, and converted my canopy height data into meters. Now, trying the same analysis for a larger (580km2) watershed I get no outputs except for log messages that the "Data source is invalid". Same source LiDAR data to derive the CHM, aspect, slope. Same data prep steps. I generated a latitude and a longitude raster map for this run. But the model doesn't like any of the data.

Are there a couple of steps I can take to track down the issue?

Is there an extent limit for the r.run tool, so the data is "invalid" because its extent is too large?